# Creating an object of a activity class in another Appcompatactivity class - android

Tags: android, android-activity, appcompatactivity

I am trying to create an object of a class, which extends from an activity class, inside the class which is extending from Appcompatactivity class.

But as soon as I call the method of the activity class through the object inside the appcompactavtivity class, the app crashes.

Can you please let me know what is the proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely positively cannot create an instance of an Android component (`Activity`, `Service`, `BroadcastReceiver`, `Provider)` using the `new` keyword.  Only the Android framework can create these instances, because it sets up the underlying `Context` as part of the object construction. You must rearchitect your app.